# Why does this function throw an "Invalid Syntax" error?

Tags: python

I am a beginner and am trying to make a function that swaps the first and last elements of a list, or the first and last letters of a word, that will work with both strings and lists.

```
def swapboth (x) :

if type(x) == str

return x[-1]+x[1:-1]+x[0]

elif type(x) == list

return [x[-1]]+x[1:-1]+[x[0]]
```

Trying to use it:

```
ns = [1,2,3]
s = "Thorsten"

swapboth(ns)
swapboth(s)
```

However I am getting an "Invalid Syntax" error on the third line, does anyone know why this may be? Many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of the `if` an `elif` lines.

Comment: Learn how to paste code into StackOverflow, you're missing all the indents which will cause a different error.

Comment: Use `isinstance` unless you need the stricter type check that `type` provides. it is considered overall more Pythonic for type checks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the formatting/syntax. First you need to put `:` at the end of the `if` and `elif` statements, and you need to put indentations as shown below:

```
def swapboth(x):
    if type(x) == str:
        return x[-1]+x[1:-1]+x[0]
    elif type(x) == list:
        return [x[-1]]+x[1:-1]+[x[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is indentation error. Python is very sensitive in case of indentation. Also, try putting colon (:) at the end of if and elif statements.

Answer (score 0):

you need to indent and use `:` to `if` to run code in python

```
def swapboth (x) :
    if type(x) == str:
        return x[-1]+x[1:-1]+x[0]
    elif type(x) == list:
        return [x[-1]]+x[1:-1]+[x[0]]
```

you can find out more here - https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Answer (score 0):

A `syntax error` means that the statements that you have written are malformed. These are the most basic errors, such as missing punctuation, closing brackets etc. Here, you're missing a `colon` at the end of each conditions.
Another thing is that you have to indent every time you use a loop , decision statement or function:
`for`, `while` , `if`, `def` .
Always remember that Python is very sensitive about indenting.
So, your code needs to be like this

```
def swapboth (x) : 
     if type(x) == str:
         return x[-1]+x[1:-1]+x[0] 
     elif type(x) == list:
         return [x[-1]]+x[1:-1]+[x[0]]
```